# How to run webpack-dev-server before run test with cypress?

Tags: testing, webpack, cypress

## Environment

- cypress : 10.7
- webpack : 5.74.0
- webpack-dev-server: ^4.10.1

## Problem

```
CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
http://localhost:3000/
```

No wonder there's an error.
But, How to start webpack-dev-server before running test with cypress ?

Comment: Use e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently to run both at once.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in the cypress documentation.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction#Solutions

In short:

```
npm i -g wait-on@latest
npm start & wait-on http://localhost:3000
cypress run
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test

throw it in your scripts section as detailed in the link and it will wait for your server to be ready before executing the cypress (or any other) npm script